# print pdf file inside navigator weasyprint

Tags: django, weasyprint

I want to print pdf file inside my browser to let the choice to save. I am using weasyprint in django 2.0.2

i use this code in my views.py but firefox download it automaticaly and don't mind about the "inline". Any help?

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="gene_detail_description_print.pdf"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Copying from there:

> The first parameter in the HTTP context is either inline (default value, 
>   indicating it can be display inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or 
>   attachment (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 
>   'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if 
>   present).
>
> ```
> Content-Disposition: inline
> Content-Disposition: attachment
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
> ```

So you should use `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="gene_detail_description_print.pdf"'` to allow the users to download the file and possibly rename it.

Comment: "attachment" must download automaticaly the file, "inline" must open it in the browser. I want it to be opened in the browser

Comment: If you want it to be opened in the browser then you'll use inline *without* the ``filename=`` part. Then firefox will open it in the browser (if the file can be opened of course).

Comment: it don't work. it is why i am asking. i just try it in google Chromium, it works well

Comment: Maybe your firefox version does not support inline pdfs.

Comment: I am using firefox 55.0.2